# How do I make a centered div stretch to 100% of the screen?

Tags: html, css, layout

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/Razman/pen/YyRZdP).
[Here](http://templated.co/solarize) is what I want to achieve.

Notice how there are several elements (the navigation menu, the header image, the green divs) that are centered on the screen but also stretch out to 100% of the screen, even when you zoom out.

How do I achieve that?

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to my site.</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p class="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="#">Learn More</a></p>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </aside>
    <article>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <h2>This is just an article</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="#">Details</a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <h2>This is just an article</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="#">Details</a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <h2>This is just an article</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="#">Details</a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <p>Fancy footer</p>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
```

---

```
body {
    background-color: #ededed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #5C4868;
    color: white;
}
header h1 {
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 0;
}
#main {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    clear: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.intro {
    width: 600px;
}
.button {
    border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
}
.button a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}
aside {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}
article {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    clear: left;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0;
}
.thumbnail {
    float: left;
    background-color: #5C4868;
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 470px;
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}
article p {

}
footer {
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #141414;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
footer p {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You remove `width: 960px;` from `.wrapper` or you move that element out of `.wrapper`

Comment: Ok, I can understand how I can do that for my header and for my footer, I actually did that.

But what if I have a div inside that wrapper? If I remove the width: 960px; won't everything just break?

Should I end the wrapper where I want my div to start and start another wrapper after that div?

Comment: Just set the wrapper width to : 100%

Comment: You can do this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPxBEX or this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwQJYr

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right then the below url will help you.
    [working jsfiddle][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/pjkrpzb1/
```

Comment: That partly answers my question.

http://codepen.io/Razman/pen/WQYKdV

What should I do if I want the red div to be like the purple header or like the footer, to stretch out like them?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper div is surrounding all your content, which giving your entire page a width of 960px, including the background.

You shouldn't place the wrapper not OVER the divs, but IN the divs.

For example your header:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
         <h1>Welcome to my site.</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

This will stretch the purple background to full width, but it will center the text to the width of 960px.

I also advice you use a `max-width` of 960px and a `width` of 100% so it will resize at smaller screens.